# How to read a XML file with spark that contains multiple namespaces?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I'm using the spark-xml library in Azure-Databricks. But I can't get the options right to read this kind of file that contains multiple namespaces.

So I'm looking for some help to get this coded in the options, or any other approach.

Here is a stripped sample.

```
<msg:TrainTrackingMessage xmlns:msg="be:brail:nmbs-it:esb:msg:traintraffic" xmlns:trtf="be:brail:nmbs-it:esb:traintraffic" xmlns:gene="be:brail:nmbs-it:esb:generalelements">
<gene:Event>
    <gene:EventType>tracking</gene:EventType>
    <gene:EventMessage>TrainTracking</gene:EventMessage>
    <gene:EventTimeStamp>2018-09-27T14:13:15.458439</gene:EventTimeStamp>
</gene:Event>
<gene:Train>
    <gene:TrainKey>
        <gene:CirculationType>1</gene:CirculationType>
        <gene:Discriminator>0</gene:Discriminator>
        <gene:DepartureDate>2018-09-27</gene:DepartureDate>
    </gene:TrainKey>
    <gene:TrainNumberEBP>2E0xaZ12</gene:TrainNumberEBP>
    <gene:TrainDetails>
        <gene:TrainGroup>1</gene:TrainGroup>
    </gene:TrainDetails>
</gene:Train>
<trtf:TrainTracking>
    <gene:ItineraryPoint>
        <gene:PtcarIdentification>592</gene:PtcarIdentification>
        <gene:OrderNumber>150</gene:OrderNumber>
        <gene:ItineraryPointDetails>
            <gene:OperationCode>=</gene:OperationCode>
            <gene:CommercialStop>2</gene:CommercialStop>
        </gene:ItineraryPointDetails>
        <gene:ItineraryPointTimeInfo>
            <gene:ArrivalTime>14:10:47</gene:ArrivalTime>
            <gene:DepartureTime>14:10:54</gene:DepartureTime>
        </gene:ItineraryPointTimeInfo>
        <gene:ItineraryTechnicalInfo>
            <gene:EngineType>21</gene:EngineType>
            <gene:TractionCode>E</gene:TractionCode>
            <gene:TractionOperator/>
        </gene:ItineraryTechnicalInfo>
    </gene:ItineraryPoint>
    <trtf:GPSPosition>
        <trtf:GPSAltitude>51</trtf:GPSAltitude>
    </trtf:GPSPosition>
    <trtf:Libelle>E2412</trtf:Libelle>
    <trtf:TrackingPointInfo>
        <trtf:TrackingType>2</trtf:TrackingType>
        <trtf:TrackingOrigin>0</trtf:TrackingOrigin>
    </trtf:TrackingPointInfo>
    <trtf:TrackingTimeInfo>
        <trtf:Delay>1639</trtf:Delay>
    </trtf:TrackingTimeInfo>
</trtf:TrainTracking>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If people would be looking for something familiar, this did the trick.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xmlfiles = dbutils.fs.ls(storage_mount_name)

##Get attribute names (for now I took all leafs of the xml structure)
firstfile = xmlfiles[0].path.replace('dbfs:','/dbfs')
root = ET.parse(firstfile).getroot()
attributes = [node.tag for node in root.iter() if len(node)==0]
clean_attribute_names = [re.sub(r'\{.*\}', '', a) for a in attributes]

#Create Dataframe and save it as csv
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=clean_attribute_names, index=xmlfiles)
for xf in xmlfiles:
    afile = xf.path.replace('dbfs:','/dbfs')
    root = ET.parse(afile).getroot()
    df.loc[afile] = [node.text for node in root.iter() if node.tag in attributes]
```