# Uploading XML data from Google Earth KML file to DataBricks

Tags: python, xml, kml, google-earth, databricks

I am setting up DataBricks to compare and contrast data from several sources.  Some of the data are in CSV files, some are in JSON format, and others are in Google Earth KML files.  The last has really been a challenge; I am trying to upload the XML data using the Data Upload function, but DataBricks cannot create a table from the XML string.  What is the procedure to insert XML into a DataBricks table?

Comment: See this thread :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52758704/how-to-read-a-xml-file-with-spark-that-contains-multiple-namespaces

Answer (score 0):

Best optimal way to use spark-xml libraries into your workspace.

Search spark-xml in maven/spark package section and follow this step to add it to the libraries https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/libraries.html#create-a-library

Attach the libraries to cluster

https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/libraries.html#attach-a-library-to-a-cluster

finally use the following code to read xml data in databricks

```
xmldata = spark.read.format('xml').option("rootTag","note").load('dbfs:/mnt/mydatafolder/xmls/note.xml')
```

Also here is the python code to do the same:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xmlfiles = dbutils.fs.ls(storage_mount_name)

##Get attribute names (for now I took all leafs of the xml structure)
firstfile = xmlfiles[0].path.replace('dbfs:','/dbfs')
root = ET.parse(firstfile).getroot()
attributes = [node.tag for node in root.iter() if len(node)==0]
clean_attribute_names = [re.sub(r'\{.*\}', '', a) for a in attributes]

#Create Dataframe and save it as csv
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=clean_attribute_names, index=xmlfiles)
for xf in xmlfiles:
    afile = xf.path.replace('dbfs:','/dbfs')
    root = ET.parse(afile).getroot()
    df.loc[afile] = [node.text for node in root.iter() if node.tag in attributes]
```